# Why doesn't my component render properly when an API returns a single record?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have custom hook which is catching data from dummyjson API. When I render products, it works fine and perfectly. When I try to catch only one product with this hook via parameter passed via URL with useParams in the end it catch this one product, but it cannot render. It seems that a single product didn't manage to load with the help of the hook before it renders. So what is difference when all products are caught are rendered correctly.

```
import axios, { Canceler } from 'axios';

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { dummyProductType } from '../types/types';

export const useFetch = ({ limit, id }: any) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<dummyProductType[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    let cancel: Canceler;

    const config =
      id === null || id === undefined
        ? {
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://dummyjson.com/products/`,
            params: { limit: limit },
            cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken((c) => (cancel = c)),
          }
        : {
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://dummyjson.com/products/${id}`,
            cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken((c) => (cancel = c)),
          };
    async function fetchData() {
      setIsLoading(true);
      {
        await axios(config)
          .then((response) => {
            if (Object.hasOwn(config, 'params')) {
              setProducts((prev) => {
                return [...prev, ...response.data.products];
              });
            } else {
              setProducts({ ...response.data });
            }
            
            if (products.length < response.data.total) setHasMore(true);
            setIsLoading(false);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            if (axios.isCancel(err)) return;
            setError(true);
          });
      }
    }
    fetchData();
    return () => cancel();
  }, [limit, id]);

  return { products, isLoading, error, hasMore };
};
```

```
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useFetch } from '../../hooks/useFetch';

import { CardProduct } from '../CardProduct';
import styles from './Cards.module.scss';

const { wrapperContainer } = styles;

const Cards = () => {
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10);
  const { products, isLoading, hasMore } = useFetch({ limit: limit });

  const observer = useRef<IntersectionObserver | null>(null);

  const lastProduct = useCallback(
    (node: Element) => {
      if (isLoading) {
        return;
      }
      if (observer.current) {
        observer.current.disconnect();
      }
      observer.current = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        if (entries[0].isIntersecting && hasMore) {
          setLimit((prev) => prev + 10);
        }
      });
      if (node) observer.current.observe(node);
    },
    [isLoading, hasMore]
  );
  console.log(products);

  return (
    <div className={wrapperContainer}>
      {products.map((product, index) => {
        if (products.length === index + 1) {
          return (
            <Link to={`books/${index + 1}`}>
              <CardProduct
                key={`${index} ${product.title}`}
                {...product}
                innerRef={lastProduct}
              />
            </Link>
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <Link to={`books/${index + 1}`}>
              <CardProduct key={`${index} ${product.title}`} {...product} />
            </Link>
          );
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cards;
```

```
import {
  Button,
  CardContent,
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardMedia,
  dividerClasses,
} from '@mui/material';
import {  useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useFetch } from '../../hooks/useFetch';


export const CardDetail = () => {

  const { id } = useParams();
  console.log(id);
  const { products, isLoading, hasMore } = useFetch({
    id: Number.parseInt(id),
  });
  console.log(products, isLoading, hasMore);

  return (
    <Card  key={id}>
      <CardHeader title={products[0].title}></CardHeader>
      <CardMedia
        component='img'
        image={products[0].thumbnail}
        sx={{ height: '150px' }}></CardMedia>
    </Card>
  );

};
```

What am I doing wrong? Or maybe it should be done different?

Comment: I feel you have some issue with 
`<CardProduct key={``${index} ${product.title}``} {...product} innerRef={lastProduct} />`
 because when you get a single product in a list, it will be a first and last product of that list and hence it'll be rendered under `products.length === index + 1` this condition. Please check if last product from list of multiple products is being rendered or not.

Comment: I think what's happening is that the API response called with the ID (the single product) is replying with an object and not an array, therefor you should wrap that object in an array: setProducts({ ...response.data }) should become setProducts({ [ response.data ] })

Comment: @SGK maybe I should add information that I try render single Product upon react-router-dom and route /books/:id, which display CardDetail component. 
'<Route path='/books/:id' element={<CardDetail />'
Cards component is displayed on another route

Comment: @ThomasSquall unfortunetly it doesn't help. When I try console.log products in CardDetail component, without rendering product properites, first it get nothing and after 3rd render it log product. When I try render product properties i get "Cannot read properties of undefined". So I think it didn't make to fetch data before rendering.

Comment: @ThomasSquall it helps :) but I have add also conditional rendering on products.length. Thank for help and hint
So I am wondering what is difference between rendering in Cards component and CardDetail component. It fetch data from same place, but if I don't add conditional rendering to CardDetail component, it throw error "Cannot read properties of undefined". Why it doesn't happen in Cards component where I don't have this?